# Deployment in heroku stopped working today

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

We are uploading an regularly with heroku-cli, but since today we receive the following error. Any ideas?

```
    $$$ heroku war:deploy target/application.war --app appname
    Uploading application.war
    java -Dheroku.appName=appname -Xmx1g -Dheroku.warFile=target/application.war -jar /Users/bermeier0/.local/share/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-java/lib/heroku-deploy-complete.jar
     ! ERROR: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/heroku/webapp-runner/9.0.30.0/webapp-runner-9.0.30.0.jar
    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/heroku/webapp-runner/9.0.30.0/webapp-runner-9.0.30.0.jar
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1456)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployWar.<init>(DeployWar.java:29)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployWar$1.apply(DeployWar.java:87)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployWar$1.apply(DeployWar.java:84)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.utils.Main.deploy(Main.java:53)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployWar.deploy(DeployWar.java:84)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployWar.main(DeployWar.java:94)
     ▸    There was a problem deploying to appname.
     ▸    Make sure you have permission to deploy by running: heroku apps:info -a appname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be that maven central repository switched to https, see [this post](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334)

Heroku released a fix for this issue. Just run

```
heroku update
```